# How to convert JSON response to PHP array

Tags: php

I'm trying to convert this response into a PHP array:

`string(734) " {"definitions":[{"text":"Informal One who is proficient at using or programming a computer; a computer buff.","attribution":"from The American Heritage\u00ae Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition"},{"text":"Informal One who uses programming skills to gain illegal access to a computer network or file.","attribution":"from The American Heritage\u00ae Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition"},{"text":"Informal One who enthusiastically pursues a game or sport: a weekend tennis hacker. ","attribution":"from The American Heritage\u00ae Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition"},{"text":"See hackie.","attribution":"from The American Heritage\u00ae Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition"}]}"`

I have tried everything from

`$string = $result;
$pattern = '\w*\(\d+\)\s';
$replacement = '';
preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$string)`

to

`$string = $result;
$pattern = '\w*\(\d+\)\s';
$replacement = '';
$def_array = str_replace($pattern,$replacement,$string);`

but when I do those they don't even change the original result.

I want to achieve something like this:
`$def_array = {"definitions":[{"text":"Informal One who is proficient at using or programming a computer; a computer buff.","attribution":"from The American Heritage\u00ae Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition"},{"text":"Informal One who uses programming skills to gain illegal access to a computer network or file.","attribution":"from The American Heritage\u00ae Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition"},{"text":"Informal One who enthusiastically pursues a game or sport: a weekend tennis hacker. ","attribution":"from The American Heritage\u00ae Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition"},{"text":"See hackie.","attribution":"from The American Heritage\u00ae Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition"}]}`

I want to go through each definition like this :

`for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($def_array[0]["definitions"]); $i++)
{
    echo $def_array[0]["definitions"][$i]["text"];
    echo "\n";
}`

I don't use json_decode because when I do I get the error `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array on the line`for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($def_array[0]["definitions"]); $i++)`.

Comment: Don't forget to select the answer if you fixed your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just the `json_decode()` function.

```
$array = json_decode($input);
```

Find more info here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: because when I do `for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($def_array[0]["definitions"]); $i++)
{
    echo $def_array[0]["definitions"][$i]["text"];
    echo "\n";
}` it gives me the error `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`.

Comment: @raindrop Use `json_decode($result, true);`. You may also use `$def_array[0]->definitions[$i]->text` instead.

Comment: when I use `json_decode($result, true);` I get the error `Notice: Undefined offset: 0` on the line `for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($def_array[0]["definitions"]); $i++)`

Comment: don't add the `[0]`.. `[definitions]` will the the first key in your array.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to select the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Parse error on line 1:
"{    "definitions"
^
Expecting '{', '['
```

The format is not valid , it must begin with { or [